# Solving the following equation without taking inverse.

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to solve the following equation for calculating the $D$:

$D=|inv(B)|*|g|$

here, $B$ is a non-singular square matrix and $g$ is a column vector of the length equal to the no of elements in the row of $B$. The modules are applied element-wise on the matrix and vector.

I want to avoid the inverse calculation procedure and rather want to obtain the solution by solving a linear equation.

Comment: You want to find $Ag$ without knowing $A$? Doesn't seem likely.

Comment: I know $B$ and $g$ both, if I wanted it without mod then simply a solution of linear equation$BD=g$ would have given me the result. Actually, I want to avoid the inverse calculation procedure and rather want to obtain the solution by solving a linear equation.

Comment: Doesn't Gaussian elimination on $|B| D = |g|$ work?

Comment: Unfortunately $|B^{-1}|\neq |B|^{-1}$ in general, for example $$\left(
\begin{matrix}
 -1 & 1 \\
 2 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)$$

Comment: Finding the inverse of a matrix *is* solving a linear equation, $BX=I$. And suppose all the entries in $B^{-1}$ are positive?

Comment: [The answers for this Math Overflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/91515/matrices-whose-inverse-is-positive) about matrices whose inverses are elementwise positive may be relevant.

Comment: @Wouter In my case, inverse of $B$ matrix is not elementwise positive.